# Interpreting low Cronbach's alpha value in CATPCA

Tags: pca, survey, eigenvalues, cronbachs-alpha

I ran categorical principal component analysis (CATPCA) on the data that I collected through a questionnaire. The purpose of the questionnaire was to understand pedestrians intentions and attitudes towards road crossing. There were 43 questions (5-point Likert type questions) in total which were expected to measure perceptions, intentions and attitude related underlying variables. After running CATPCA on the obtained data, I got the results as shown in the Figure.

[image]

Only 5-dimensional solution is shown here. All these components have eigenvalues greater than 1 and they explain 44% of the variance. However, the Cronbach's alpha value is lower than 0.7 for the last two components. If I remove those two components, then the explained variance is only 33%.

My questions are:

1. If Cronbach's alpha value is less than 0.7 but eigenvalue is higher than 1 for a certain component, should I discard that component?
2. Does total Cronbach alpha hold any value? I mean if individual Cronbach alphas are low but the total is as high as 0.9 (as shown in Fig), can we conclude that scale is internally consistent?

Comment: Why are you using 0.7 as a cutoff for alpha?

Comment: The following paper mentions reports about the acceptable values of alpha, ranging from 0.7 to 0.95.
Tavakol, Mohsen, and Reg Dennick. "Making sense of Cronbach's alpha." International journal of medical education 2 (2011): 53.

Comment: Interestingly, they cite Nunnally and Bernstein - everyone cites Nunnally and Bernstein as saying that 0.7 is a cut-off. Nunnally and Bernstein don't say that. They have a nuanced discussion about when you should use different cut-offs (if at all). I once reviewed a paper who cited N&B for a 0.7 cut-off. I said they shouldn't, because N&B don't say that. They said "Everyone says N&B said this, so we will say it too." Bland and Altman are not experts in this area. I don't recall what DeVellis says.

Comment: As Statistics is not my major so I found it difficult to defend an alpha value below 0.7 (given the fact that many published papers use 0.7 as a threshold).

Comment: I'm not a stats major either. :)  Everyone blindly uses 0.7 because everyone else blindly uses 0.7.

Comment: I got your point :)